# Laravel 8 PDOException::("could not find driver")

Tags: laravel, pdo

After some months I returned to my working project.
The site work as earlier - all records retrieved from postgresql database.
But when i run
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
I recieved
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

could not find driver (SQL: select tablename from pg_catalog.pg_tables where schemaname in ('public'))

PDOException::("could not find driver")

But on frontend side - in browser - all work fine - thr problem only while seeding

Comment: _But on frontend side - in browser - all work fine_ - Are you viewing pages that actually query the database? Have you confirmed that the `php-mysql` extension is installed on the server?

Comment: your php command line binary might be using a different php installation than your browser. You can compare the output of `php -m` in the command line with the output of `phpinfo()` on a website